# Is $f(x,y)=g(x \cdot y) $ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f(x, y) = g(xy)$ where $g :\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Is $f$ continuous?

Proof: Consider $H(x)=x$ and $Z(y)=y$  both of these functions are continuous so is their product $K(x,y)=x \cdot y$. Now since both $g,K$ are continuous so $g\circ K$  which means $f(x,y)=g(x \cdot y) $ is continuous. Is my proof correct. If so any alternative proofs a bit more rigorous using the Open preimage Definition of continuity .?

Comment: it is quite right.

Comment: Your proof is fine. In proving that the composition of continuous functions is continuous, the "preimages of open sets are open" definition was used (or, in this case, an epsilon-delta definition, which in the case of $\Bbb R$ ultimately amounts to the same thing). So you don't have to re-prove it.